# Why does this function CPS function work in Chrome but not other browsers?

Tags: javascript, continuation-passing

i have tried to execute this simple code, about CPS.
This works in Chrome 43, but not in Firefox and Opera ...
what's wrong ? (s.o. Linux Mint 17 )

```
(function(){

  var i = 0;
  function forloop(){
    if(i<10){
      document.write(i)
      i++; 
      setTimeout(forloop, 0);
    }
  }

  forloop();
})();
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Just tested on Firefox Dev Edition and it's okay, it logs all the `i` (I replaced your write with a `console.log`).

Comment: What do you expect the code to do and what does it do in Firefox?

Comment: in firefox does not appear all digit, but show only 0, then execution stop

Comment: Don't ever use `document.write` in an asynchronous function.

Comment: ok but does not explain, beacause in Chrome works ... and no,  in other two browser ...  about console , i have tried all works good in all browser !

Comment: `document.write` seems like one of those old things still in JavaScript because of JavaScript reasons. Using the cleaner `console.log` works okay.

Comment: Just for the reference: [Why is document.write considered a “bad practice”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/1048572). If this has helped you, I'm inclined to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is: `document.write` smells bad and seems like a remnant of dark forgotten pasts.
Don't use that. Use `console.log`, or even append to some HTML, but not `document.write`.

This works perfectly across all normal browsers :

```
(function(){

  var i = 0;
  function forloop(){
    if(i<10){
      console.log(i);
      i++; 
      setTimeout(forloop, 0);
    }
  }

  forloop();
})();
```